# Shared Pointers declaration

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, shared

I'm modifying my code to include shared pointers instead of raw pointers. Is the following declaration valid?

```
for(//some loop//){

std::shared_ptr<foo> tmp;
/..do stuff to tmp../
vectorofpointer.push_back(tmp);
```

Additionally, once tmp goes out of scope, will this affect my vector?

Comment: yes, it can, it keeps a `nullptr` and is said "not to own an object"

Comment: depends how vectorofpoint is declared

Comment: if tmp is valid pointer by the time it is pushed, and if push_back takes foo*, then when the calling function goes out of scope, tmp is freed/destucted, you would have to detach tmp to avoid the automatic behavior

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is ok.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr:

> 1) Default constructor constructs a shared_ptr with no managed object, i.e. empty `shared_ptr`

See also http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr:

> A shared_ptr may also own no objects, in which case it is called empty […]

If your vector holds `shared_ptr` elements, your can still access the object pointed to after `tmp` has gone out of scope, since the reference count keeps the object alive.